# Microsoft Graph: insert a message (mail) to user inbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a Microsoft application (with Mail.Read/Write permissions) and I need to insert a mail (.eml extension file) to a user inbox.

Is that possible? I know that with Gsuite that can be done using the 'insert' API and was wondering if something similar exist with Graph API.

I'm not talking about sending new mail to the user or about inserting an attachment to existing message in the user inbox, but to insert completely new email to his inbox (without having to go through SPF or whatever checks that take place before mails usually get into end users inboxes).

Looking into Mail section under Graph API documentation wasn't so helpful.

If that not possible, perhaps there is a workaround?

EDIT: seems like the best option is to use "send mail" API and specify "saveToSentItems": False.. the only issue here as that my application will need to request the Mail.Send permission as well..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the send mail api as all your doing is creating an Item in the Mailbox. If you want it to appear as a Sent Mail (rather then a draft) you do need to set the  PidTagMessageFlags extended property (the same as you would in EWS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-import-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange). Also if you want it to appear if its been sent in the past there are few additional extended properties you need to set. eg

```html
{
    "Subject": "test1234",
    "Sender": {
        "EmailAddress": {
            "Name": "blah",
            "Address": "blah@blah.com"
        }
    },
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "123Body"
    },
    "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "PropertyId": "Integer 0x0E07",
            "Value": "1"
        },
        {
            "PropertyId": "SystemTime 0x0039",
            "Value": "2019-06-12T10:10:47.2048+10:00"
        },
        {
            "PropertyId": "SystemTime 0x0E06",
            "Value": "2019-06-12T10:10:47.2048+10:00"
        }
    ]
}
```